# Error when running callback function in Jest using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I have defined function `runSafelyAsync` that is a wrapper for the promises that should be ran asynchronously, allowing the calling function to continue without waiting. setTimeout is to always defer starting the function execution. The code is as follows:

```js
export function runSafelyAsync(fn: () => Promise<unknown>): void {
    const backgroundFn = async () => {
        try {
            return await fn();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    };

    setTimeout(backgroundFn, 1);
}
```

In one use case, I am using it to send email without blocking the entire flow behind it. Example use-case:

```js
runSafelyAsync(() => {
   this.userService.sendEmail(); // it's async function
}
```

On the real Node.js app instance it works well and doing its job. Then, I have some unit & E2E tests via Jest touches code above and the test fails with following error message:

`this.userService.sendEmail is not a function`

I have tried to mock this function to be as easy as possible and the error still occurs.

```
jest.spyOn(asyncUtils, 'runSafelyAsync').mockImplementation((callback) => callback());
```

I am using jest ^28.0.2, with Nest.js framework. Why it is happening only in Jest environment?

Answer (score 1):

`this.userService.sendEmail is not a function`

The error you are encountering is because you are not mocking the `userService` object to have a `sendEmail()` stub. Your mocked implementation of `runSafelyAsync()` *still calls the passed function*, which therefore needs to exist.

What you need to do is either mock out the `sendEmail()` function (this is the preferred approach) or change your implementation of the mocked `runSafelyAsync()` to not actually call the passed function. Either approach should remove the error you are getting.

Comment: Tks! It's clearer to me now, but can you explain please why it happens only when I call it through runSafelyAsync? If I'd normally call it, like "await this.userService.sendEmail()" test passes

Comment: @FilipSzymański I can't say for sure without seeing all your code but I assume it's a difference in how you're mocking things? If you need initialisation code to run in a module but it's mocked, then you wind up with an empty object and a nonexistent function.